# Wrong Decimal Converting from Double to String in java

Tags: java, android, casting, double

I have A String that is formatted correctly to be cast to a double and it works fine for most decimals. The issue is that for .33, .67, and possibly others I haven't tested, the decimal becomes something like `.6700000000002`, or `.329999999998`. I understand why this happens but does any one have a suggestion to fix it.

Comment: Welcome to the world of floating point numbers :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a result of [IEEE-754](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point) rounding rules, some numbers cannot be represented precisely in [two's complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement). For example, `1/10` is not precisely representable.

You can add more precision (but not infinite) by using [BigDecimal](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html).

```
BigDecimal oneTenth = new BigDecimal("1").divide(new BigDecimal("10"));
System.out.println(oneTenth);
```

Which outputs `0.1`

Answer (score 3):

Some decimal numbers can not be represented accurately with the internal base 2 machine representation.

Comment: ah that would make sense. So this has to do with IEEE floating point standard I'm assuming? Any idea how to fix it

Comment: @KBusc, I believe the IEEE-754 standard actually allows decimal floating-point representation (useful for accounting and finance). So it's really tied to the fact that your target is using a base 2 representation (like most targets).

Answer (score 1):

That's double precision for you. Binary numbers and decimals don't work well together. Unless you are doing something really precise it should be fine, if you are printing it you should use either decimal format or printf.

Comment: well seeing as this is in java I wont be using printf

Comment: @KBusc You [might](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#printf%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...%29).

Comment: really? I never knew that only seen it in C/C++ any ways please see the question Edit

Answer (score 1):

Value of floating point numbers are not stored directly but with exponential values. You may write 3.1233453456356 as number, but this is stored something like 3 and 2^6 in memory. It tries to store a value as close as your number, but those differences can happen.

Answer (score 1):

It shouldn't be a problem unless you're testing for equality. With floating-point tests for equality you'll need to allow a "delta" so that:

```
if (a == b)
```

becomes

```
if (abs(a-b) < 0.000001)
```

or a similar small delta value. For printing, limit it to two decimal places and the formatter will round it for you.